# Different query results in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a question in prolog. Here is the Knowledge Base.

```
loves(vincent,mia).
loves(marcellus,mia).
loves(pumpkin,honey_bunny).
loves(honey_bunny,pumpkin).

jealous(X,Y) :-
   loves(X,Z),
   loves(Y,Z).
```

This is from "[Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)"  book. Now if I make a query `?- jealous(marcellus,W).`  it  returns that `W = vincent`  but if I give the query `?- jealous(vincent,W).`  the return result is `W=vincent` So this means that vincent is jealous of himself but marcellus is not jealous of himself. Why is the answer different ?
I am using swipl in Ubuntu Linux , which is in VirtualBox on winxp. I am beginner in Prolog.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the answer `W = vincent` at the query `?- jealous(marcellus,W).`  type `;` instead of `Enter`  and you will get `W = marcellus.`
You must add the fact that `X \= Y` in `jealous/2`.

Comment: In SWI or GNU, you can type also SPACE which is a bit more comfortable.