# SWI-Prolog Editor accepts invalid encoding

Tags: prolog, editor, swi-prolog

(was : **Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated**).
I am learning Prolog using SWI-Prolog version 8.2.1 and reading the Learn Prolog Now! book.
I have a problem with Knowledge Base 5 (also available online [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse1)) :

```
    loves(vincent,mia).
    loves(marcellus,mia).
    loves(pumpkin,honey_bunny).
    loves(honey_bunny,pumpkin).
    
    jealous(X,Y) :- loves(X,Z),loves(Y,Z).
```

When I consult it, SWI-Prolog raises an error :
**ERROR:    Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated**
It seems strange, since this book is recommended by many as a good Prolog book,
and I also found a question on SO [Different query results in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757406/different-query-results-in-prolog) about the very same code
that does not mention any error.
Is this an issue of SWI-Prolog ?
Or is the code wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Well, it turned out that this is not related to the code at all.
I copied the code from the pdf version of the book and pasted it in
the SWI-Prolog Editor and saved it.
Opening the file with Notepad++, under the Encoding menu, it shows 'UCS2 LE BOM', while it should be 'UTF-8' for a text file.
I changed the encoding to UTF-8 and SWI-Prolog compiles it.
Case closed.
It beats, though, that a programming editor accepts happily an invalid file
without even a warning.

I thought I could just delete this question, but maybe this can help someone else
dealing with the same problem.